# Combining several rasters before r.surf.contour?

Tags: raster, grass-gis, dem, elevation, overlay

I have been trying to generate an elevation model from contour lines using first *v.to.rast.attr* and then *r.surf.contour*.  Generally, it works pretty well, execpt for one issue.  My data contains a lot of sea without contours, and *r.surf.contour* spends a lot of time in the sea region where there are no pixels in the raster generated from *r.to.rast.attr*. Actually, I'm running one now on a reasobly large area, and after 24 hours, it is at 70%.

The solution for me would be simple.  I have sea polygons (and even lake polygons with elevation). I could generate a separatr raster for that using *v.to.rast.attr*.

But then I need to combine the two rasters into a single raster before running *r.surf.contour*.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 2):

If you do not need the bathymetry, then **don't** combine the sea raster with the land elevation raster. Instead use it as a mask as follows:

Make your sea polygon into a raster:

```
v.to.rast sea output=sea use=value val=1
```

Then make a land area raster ("inverse" of the sea):

```
r.mapcalc "land_area = if(sea==1, null(), 1)"
```

Now set the land_area as a mask, and do your r.surf.contour:

```
r.mask land_area
r.surf.contour...
```